# Problem with launching silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, debugging

I'm running silverlight 4 application and I see in browser the progress circle, but one second it disappears.

I'm use f5 (when I am in address bar, and in output there is nothing new.

While I'm first starting application there is no error.

How can I found source of this problem?

I can't attach to process Silverlight in chrome, because I have'nt got it on the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean Solution has helped me. Now application works :)

As another tip check console of Chrome(Ctrl Shift I)

Answer (score 1):

This means you have an error in your Silverlight application (most likely XAML error).

- Look in your Visual Studio "Output" window.
- Enable debugging on your web project for Silverlight.